# Magento 1.14 custom skin not applied to products

Tags: theme, magento-enterprise, breadcrumbs, skin

I created a custom design skin and assigned it to some categories under *Manage Categories/Custom Design* tab, and selected **Yes** to *Apply To Products*.  This works fine if the user drills down through the category, series(sub-category), then to the product page from the product listings.

Where it doesn't work is when the product appears on the right column under 'Recently Viewed Products' and is clicked from there.

The difference appears to have something to do with the URL format or breadcrumbs.  From the series page, then products URLs are hierarchical as `domain/category/series/product` and the skin is applied correctly.

When the links appear as recently viewed they are just as `domain/product`.  It's when the page displays like this (and missing the category/series breadcrumbs) that it breaks by show the default skin even though the product belongs to the category with the custom skin.

So I'm not sure if this is a skin bug or a breadcrumb bug, but the crumbs look the same in Magento2.   I don't care about how the breadcrumbs show, I just need the custom skin applied to the product based on its owner category.   Any ideas?

Comment: Does it even attempt to load them if you check the network requests?

Comment: No, no attempt to load the skin files.